# How to log activities across multiple requests

Tags: php

Our site makes heavy use of AJAX, and ends up calling several different PHP files in the background to fill individual tabs. Specifically, JQuery and DataTables are used. Because PHP is stateless, I'm struggling to create an activity log to work across all requests for a single session (e.g., all SQL queries performed for this page view) as each PHP file executes its own queries in its own state, so they are unaware of each other.

Any tips on how to handle this? I fear I'm overcomplicating matters or missing an obvious solution.

In the end, ideally the footer of our application can say something like: Your application performed 6 SQL queries, here they are: ....

I don't require specific code, but hopefully the above makes sense and a Eureka moment can be discovered.

Comment: having you looked into using PHP sessions to store variables.  Might work for you if I understand you correctly.  Sessions will flow from page to page once set

Comment: @Austin the trouble is the data will be preserved longer than I'd like, as for example with "This page performed 6 queries..." will increment to 12, 18, 24, ..., until they close their browser. Well, sort of. :) Suppose I could create a unique id on top of my page and then associate queries to that? That might work.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using Jquery would be for each $.post Ajax call to pass a callback function. The callback then adds the result when returned from the server to a DIV or a js array.

Ajax post could be:

```
$.post(server_url, params, my_callback, "json")
```

and callback:

```
function my_callback(response) {

   $("#thediv").append(response)

}
```

This would asynchronously log each response in the div with id "thediv"

Comment: I like the idea, and wish I better understood jQuery and JS in general. But being an old-timer server-side human, I fear it'd end up being too difficult for me. About 7 different requests make a single page. But, I may end up trying your method as it appears reasonable.